# Anime: male fighter in Guyver-looking biometric armor, destroyed planet where robot lives but fear their death by rust

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

Cartoon Network/Adult Swim/Toonami/Boomerang, in English language.

At the beginning of the show there were these robot monsters that were attacking a village or a town. The whole planet was destroyed only live robots but they all feared their lives be ended by rust and corrosion.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please check out this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/101407) to see if you can think of any more details to [edit] in.  What is "biometric armour?"

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like [Casshern Sins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casshern_Sins) (2008). The elements that fit are

1. Aired on Adult Swim/Cartoon Network
2. The world is mostly a wasteland. Humanity is nearly extinct
3. Robots are afraid of dying via rust

   > Robots fare little better, fearing death as much as humans do: the poisonous environment quickly causes their mechanical bodies to rust and corrode, forcing them to regularly replace their damaged parts, if spare parts in good condition can even be found.
4. Casshern looks a bit like Guyver

   [image: picture of biometric armor]